# Why are there no jungle rules in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, terrain

This is far from a game breaking oversight but it been bugging me for sometime.

Why isn't Jungle part of the rules for different environments?

Now ever since Tolkien the fantasy genre has as a rule been Eurocentric with a focus on western feudalistic societies. As a result most natural environments and settings depicted in fantasy is usually Northern European forests and mountains. DnD's different settings through the years has been no exception.
That said not including one of the largest natural environments on Earth in the core rules is kind of a glaring oversight.

I feel it worth stifling one counter-argument I know will crop up before it does. Jungle isn't (or at least shouldn't be) covered by the rules for forests. It's easy to equate jungle with rainforest. The thing is not all jungles are rainforests nor is all rainforests jungles. In fact, there exists coniferous rainforests. Just as there exists plenty of jungles that isn't forests at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about designer reasons are no longer allowed on RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/questions-about-designer-reasons-are-off-topic).

Comment: @V2Blast This is a perfectly fine question for a frame challenge, like Theik’s answer gives. The question presupposes that there are no jungle rules, but there are (if you look in the ToA adventure)

Comment: @illustro Unfortunately capacity for correcting the mistakes in the question doesn't override the fact the nature of the question is off topic. It could instead be edited into something along the lines of “Are there jungle rules? I can't find them.” though.

Comment: This is indeed off topic as a designer reasons question, but I've closed it as a duplicate of the follow-up topical question asking what jungle rules are available.

Answer (score 5):

## There are rules for jungles

The DM manual has all kinds of rules that can be adapted for jungles. Hot temperatures, quicksand, diseases, all these things function perfectly in a jungle.

However, the main focus of the published D&D adventures tends to be the Sword Coast, which is scarce on jungles. If you want to go more in-depth on jungle survival, look no further than the *Tomb of Annihilation* campaign book, which has more detailed rules on the kind of food you might find in the jungle, how much water you need to drink, and why it's a terrible idea to drink from jungle streams.

Comment: In you second paragraph, by "the D&D campaigns", do you mean the published adventures?

Comment: I do, I'll clarify.