# Are there published rules for navigating and travelling through jungles?

Tags: dnd-5e, travel, terrain

I’m interested in designing part of my D&D campaign to have a jungle environment which the players will potentially need to navigate at some point.

Does D&D 5e have published rules for navigating and travelling through jungles?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130067/why-are-there-no-jungle-rules-in-5e)

Comment: Tags are also meant to make it easier for non technical users to find related questions. The type of environment is a key portion of this question, and thus useful in my opinion.

Comment: @illustro I created a [meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8280/do-we-need-a-jungle-tag) question asking about the tag. Feel free to drop in and offer your thoughts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## There are rules for jungles

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* has all kinds of rules that can be adapted for jungles. [Hot temperatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/adventure-environments#ExtremeHeat) (p. 110), [quicksand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/adventure-environments#Quicksand) (p. 110), [diseases](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/running-the-game#Diseases) (p. 256-257), all these things function perfectly in a jungle.

However, the main focus of the published D&D adventures tends to be the Sword Coast, which is scarce on jungles. If you want to go more in-depth on jungle survival, look no further than the *Tomb of Annihilation* campaign book, which has more detailed rules on the kind of food you might find in the jungle, how much water you need to drink, and why it's a terrible idea to drink from jungle streams.

Comment: It might be helpful to point out where any or all of these rules live in the DMG as it is not always the most intuitively layed out.

Comment: As @Rubiksmoose mentioned it would be helpful to point out where these rules live in the DMG.

Comment: It might help to emphasize the point that ToA has fully fleshed-out rules for jungle adventure, whereas the DMG only provides some building blocks and general guidance for an adventure designer.

Comment: Will update with more specifics when I get home.

Comment: @Theik I’m just waiting for those references/clarifications before accepting this answer (without those the answer isn’t quite complete)

Comment: @illustro My bad, I had tagged myself to add it and completely forgot somehow. Added the page references!